# forcing crash on Unity iOS application for Crashlytic dashboard test

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I have been trying to crash my iOS application to see if Crashlytic would catch it. I have tried some method to create a crash case but the best I could do is just create an exception or just freeze the app but not enough to crash it. do you know a way to crash the Unity iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that ending its process forcefully will generate a crash. On Mac, simply press Option + Command + Escape and it will bring up a menu from which you can force quit the app.